# Comment prononcer le mot « gaspillions »?

Tags: prononciation, phonétique

Comment prononcer le mot « gaspillions » surtout la combination « ill » suivi d'un « i»? Est-ce qu'on prononce le son "y" pour « ill » et puis le refaire pour le « i » suivant? Ou est-ce qu'on le prononce qu'une seule fois?

Merci d'avance!

Answer (score 7):

Officiellement, la prononciation est identique (ou quasi-identique selon les sources) à l'imparfait et au présent, donc ici `[gaspijɔ̃]`. C'est le "i" de l'imparfait qui permet de faire la distinction entre les temps, ce qui donne lieu pour certains verbes à un enchaînement de plusieurs "i" (*nous riions, nous priions, nous skiions...*).

Quelques ressources : [1](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-94491.php), [2](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-103699.php), [3](https://sosgrammaire.hebfree.org/impindier.html), [4 (ne parle pas de l'imparfait mais mentionne la phonétique des verbes en -iller)](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4795).

Je pense que cela dépend des régions, mais **personnellement**, j'aurais tendance à accentuer un peu plus longuement le son "i" à l'imparfait, pour être sûr que l'interlocuteur comprenne que j'utilise l'imparfait et non le présent. En phonétique, cela donne quelque chose comme `[gaspijiɔ̃]`.

Un exemple avec cette phrase (qui n'a pas beaucoup de sens) :

> Dans les années 80, nous gaspillions plus qu'aujourd'hui, car nous avons mis en place le tri sélectif.

Je me suis enregistré en train de la prononcer de la façon la plus intelligible possible, le résultat peut être écouté [ici](https://voca.ro/18ai6LgV7ge7). J'ai volontairement insisté sur le son "i" plus que je ne l'aurais fait de façon naturelle.

Answer (score 3):

Je plussoie la réponse de Reyedy qui est la bonne.

Il faut cependant avoir à l'esprit que la forme verbale ***nous gaspillions*** est extrêmement rare à l'oral, comme l'est par exemple ***nous criions***.

On entendra bien plus souvent ***on gaspillait*** et ***on criait*** qui ont le mérite d'une prononciation bien distincte du présent ***on gaspille*** et ***on crie***.

D'autre part, la prononciation [gaspijɔ̃] ou [gaspijjɔ̃] est spécifique aux verbes. S'il s'était agit d'un nom commun, sa prononciation aurait probablement été [gaspiljɔ̃] avec la même terminaison que *millions*, *billions* et *trillions*.